# OAuth Access Token life span

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have an api runs a long time. What if an access token expires during the api run? will the api stop in the middle or keep running until it ends?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API. Usually the API will validate the token when it receives the request and then process it. During processing usually expiration is not checked - the API only cares that the token was valid when it received the request.

Of course I can imagine that someone implemented an API, that during processing of long requests it validates the token in set intervals. I would imagine that you would have information on such behaviour in the API's documentation, though.